# How to use PYTHONPATH with VSCode Python Extension for Debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

I'm working on a project which is structured like

```
Parent Directory
----+ MyPackage
     ----__init__.py
     ----file1.py
----+ Tests
     ----test.py
```

When I run the tests from terminal, I use

```
PYTHONATH=./ python ./Tests/test.py
```

Now, when I try the debug option after installing 'Python Extension', error is raised

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module names 'MyPackage'
```

How can I put PYTHONPATH to the debug configuration such that it will taken care?

Comment: On Windows, the environment variable 'path' should point to your Python installation, meaning the interpreter. If VS Code is using the environment variable 'pythonpath', you should be able to add the path to your own module so that VS Code knows where to look for stuff to import.

Comment: @rok No, that is wrong. Please read the official documentation regarding PYTHONPATH environment variable: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: @niid. Thanks. Removed

Answer (score 7):

After some search and trial and error, I found something that works. I'm posting it here so that people looking for the same problem can also try.
I'm not sure whether this is the right way to do t.

Create (or add to) a file `.vscode/settings.json` the contents as

```
{
    // .. any other settings
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
}
```

Now I'm able to run my project with the package.

Comment: That solution will only work when you do something that runs through the terminal (e.g. debugging), but it won't work for things when the interpreter does it on your behalf (e.g. runs tests using the Test Explorer). You can also [define an environments definition file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) which should work in all instances.

Comment: @Brett I'm not sure .env works any longer for python.pythontPath. See the note below #3: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Answer (score 6):

In VSCode 1.74.0 I got it to work by putting the path in my debugging `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python debugging"
            "type": "python"
            // other settings
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using venv I have tried every variation of tinkering with the `terminal.integrated.env.x` setting, and `env`/`cwd` in `launch.json` and while I could get this scenario OK when running a file, I could not get it working correctly when debugging a file.

So, what I ended up doing was modifying the `.venv/bin/activate` file locally to add the project to the python path as part of activation. I think this solution is fine as the venv is to be used only with this project and it covers all scenarios of running files within the IDE.

I added this to the bottom of `myProject/.venv/bin/activate`:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/path/to/your/project/:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

For most people the best option is probably to just put

```
PYTHONPATH="${env:PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}"
```

into an `.env` file in the root of the workspace. This will add the workspace folder to PYTHONPATH without overriding it.

However, if you only want to the environment variable to be added to the integrated terminal, then you can add this to your settings

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.<<OS>>": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
```

where `<<OS>>` can be eg. `linux`, `osx` or `windows`

*** NB! Remeber to restart the integrated terminal after adding this ***