# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' in python

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

```
src
 |_ __init__.py
    example.py
test
 |_ test.py
```

```py
# __init__.py
class API:
    def something(self):
        print('folder src | file __init__')
```

```py
# example.py
class Example:
    def doingSomething(self):
        print('folder src | file example')
```

```py
# test.py
import src
from src.example import Example

class Test:
    def somethingElse(self):
        print('folder test | file test')
```

when I run the `test.py` file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<my path>\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import src
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, check my answer to get it configured correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76055855/1563072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you import the `example` module in your `src/__init__.py` file, you need to specify the module name (i.e., `example`) within the package (i.e., `src`).

```
from src.example import Example
```

Comment: ok thanks, but I'm still getting the same error from the first line of test.py

Comment: That means that the src package is not in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: How do I put it in my PYTHONPATH? I'm using vscode

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570503/how-to-use-pythonpath-with-vscode-python-extension-for-debugging) might be useful.

Comment: try using the below
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

Comment: What should I add in my `.vscode/settings.json` file? I am on windows 10. The import sys didn't work and I can't find an answer on both links posted by @abc

Answer (score -2):

You don't actually need to include the "src" folder in your path. For example, if you're folder structure looks like this:

- src

  - app1

    - models1.py
    - views1.py
  - app2

    - models2.py
    - views2.py

You can import models2.py into views2.py like this:

```
from .models2 import ClassName
```